# Can't change library versioning settings

Tags: 2010, document-library, versioning, team-sites

In SharePoint 2010, I have a default document library in a customized team site template (which I didn't create). When I try to change the versioning settings in the library to `Create major and minor (draft) versions` and click `OK`, the changes won't "stick" or take affect. If I change the settings from `No versioning` to `Create major versions` or vice versa, then the changes WILL stick.

[image: Versioning settings]

You can see in the image that it appears that the option for major and minor versioning is available. What am I missing here? Could this be something to do with the customized team site template?

Comment: I wouldn't think the custom site template would be the issue but you never know. What happens if you try to create another library in the same site? What about creating libraries in different sites? Do they show the same behaviour?

Comment: Problems like this make me suspect a faulty xml definition in the backend. Try extracting it and see if there're odd settings in there.

Comment: @PaulLucas if I create a library in the same site, it has the same behavior (I can't make the "Create major and minor versions" stick or take affect). If I create a library in a different site, then it will work correctly.